# The method of difference

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that $\sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+3}=\frac{5}{6}-\frac{2n+5}{(n+2)(n+3)}$

How do I use method of difference to solve this. I tried to list out the numbers, which went,

1/2 - 1/4,
1/3 - 1/5,
1/4 - 1/6,
....
1/n - 1/(n+2)
1/(n+1) - 1/(n+3)

I found out I couldn't really cancel out the in between terms. What modification should I do, or is there no way at all I can approach this question by the means of method of difference ?

Comment: You could also use induction.

Comment: NS John- I am just interested.How did you find this sum using method of differences as the OP asked( not induction)

Comment: @N.S.JOHN, can I really cancel all the in between terms ?

Comment: NS john, you are right, I can cancel out some of the terms, it leaves me with the same answer. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually cancel out many terms of the sum.

$$\begin{aligned} A &= \sum_{x=1}^n \left[\frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x+3}\right]\\ &= \sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{x+1} - \sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{x+3}\\
\end{aligned}$$
We use $u = x+2$ in the second sum
$$\begin{aligned}
A &= \left(\sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{x+1}\right) - \left(\sum_{u=3}^{n+2} \frac{1}{u+1}\right) \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{1 + 1} + \frac{1}{2+1} + \sum_{x=3}^{n} \frac{1}{x+1} \right) - \left(\frac{1}{(n+1) + 1} + \frac{1}{(n+2) + 1} + \sum_{u=3}^{n} \frac{1}{u+1}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+3}
\end{aligned}$$

Then you just have to sum everything.

Comment: You made it look so simple!

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this by induction.

---

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$\sum\limits_{x=1}^{1}\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+3}=\frac{5}{6}-\frac{2+5}{(1+2)(1+3)}$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+3}=\frac{5}{6}-\frac{2n+5}{(n+2)(n+3)}$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$\sum\limits_{x=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+3}=$

$\color\red{\sum\limits_{x=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+3}}+\frac{1}{n+1+1}-\frac{1}{n+1+3}=$

$\color\red{\frac{5}{6}-\frac{2n+5}{(n+2)(n+3)}}+\frac{1}{n+1+1}-\frac{1}{n+1+3}=$

$\frac{5}{6}-\frac{2(n+1)+5}{(n+1+2)(n+1+3)}$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.